# Is there an easy way to track # of operations on EOS in a single day?

Tags: cleos, blockchains

I need to know the daily operations on the EOS blockchain. I understand that each transaction can have several operations.

If I set up a node on my computer how would I start counting operations?

Alternative: Any APIs

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use the [RPC-Api](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference) and a public endpoint.

Start with the first block of the day you want to count the actions for and call [get_info](http://get_info) until the last block of the day while counting and calculating the amount of actions/operations(actions and context-free actions per transaction) executed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @cmadh would work in principle, but you would have to make sure you successfully called `get_info` for each block across the day, and you might get rate-limited or face connectivity issues etc. that would screw this up.

An alternative way to do it would be to run your own instance of `nodeos` that is connected to the EOS Mainnet, and write a simple plugin to record each action from every transaction across a day into a file.

If you aren't willing to go to the effort of making a plugin, you can parse your log files for your nodeos, which will tell you the number of transactions in each block. You can then extract those numbers and sum them up, but it will only tell you the number of transactions and not the number of actions within those transactions.

Answer (score 0):

**For No of Actions**
You can run an instance of nodeos that is connected EOS mainnet with MongoDB or state history plugin enabled and create a node service that fetches data from actions_traces collection of DB and filter them based on timestamps. Each action is stored with property createdAt that has timestamp of when action is created so it will be easy.
Note that this will include both executed and failed actions if you only want to consider executed ones you can filter that too.